# Create a user with access only via SSH

Tags: ssh, osx-lion

I am trying to create a completely hidden user in Lion that can only login via SSH, or at a minimum cannot login via the login window.

I am trying to create a user for remote system management.  I have used the excellent CreateLionUser.pkg included in instaDMG to create hidden admin user, but the account still shows up in the Users & Groups preference pane. Additionally the login window lists Other... as a login option.

I am trying to prevent this option from being seen by the end user, since it should not be used to login locally to the system. Also, since this is for patching and other system management I don't want the user to accidentally delete the user from the preference pane.

In previous versions of OSX if you set the UID to under 100 the account was ignored.  This trick, and others, do not seem to be working in Lion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for the hiding of the Other option:

`sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.loginwindow SHOWOTHERUSERS_MANAGED -bool false`

[From here.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/19890/how-do-you-hide-users-from-login-and-fast-user-switching-under-os-x-10-7-lion)